# Scraping multiple websites with approximate URLs for a particular String

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape multiple websites and export the information to a `.csv` or ideally `.xslx` file.
So far I have accomplished to scrape one site with multiple entries using this code:

```
import requests
r = requests.get("https://www.company_name/our-portfolio-companies")

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
doc = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

for company_headline in doc.select(".company_headline a"):
    name = company_headline.text
    
for website in doc.select(".subinfo_website"):
    website = website.text[19:]
```

What came out was a list of the portfolio companies and their respective websites within my Jupiter notebook. I took the easy way out and just copy/pasted the info straight into Excel to further pretty it up there.

However, I am stuck in the next step. If I would now try to find the address of each of the ~400 portfolio companies that I found. I first off need to find out where that info is hidden. My idea would be to ask Python to ping each of the respective ~400 sites with an added `./contact-us`, `./contact`, `./about-us` etc. and to list it in case it receives a 200 reply.
Then in a next step search the HTML for words like "address:" and copy the next 40 letters of string.

Am I on the right track here? Can someone help me out or point me in the right direction where I can read more to figure out how this would be done?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome! This is a strange case and I doubt there is a definitive answer, but I'll have a go.

As far as I can tell, you are on the right track. Most websites will have their URLs matching that, but this won't work 100% of the time. One thing that you could do is scrape the page (or even just the footer) for a link that has the text contact/contact us/etc to find the URL for the contact rather than hoping it matches one of your guess URLs.